# Can we get transposed resultset of stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, transpose

I know that we can use PIVOT\UNPIVOT in SELECT statement to get the transpose of result set.

However, this time I am facing a scenario where I am getting result set from a stored procedure.

Also, the output given by stored procedure is not fixed but changes dynamically. So exact number of ROWS in actual output is not fixed OR in other words, exact number of COLUMNS in transposed result set is not fixed.

So I am not able to think of solution which can give me the transposed result set of stored procedure.

Can this be done?

Comment: Why not you use dynamic query(so you extract columns)

Comment: Isn't there any system SP\function already created for that!